How can I get 'Tileiconifier' to FIND Microsoft Edge PWAs/Progressive Web Apps?
I'm using the app called: 'Tileiconifier' to further customize the size of the app icons in the start menu, but the problem is within 'Tileiconifier' I can't find ANY of the websites that I have installed as PWAs/Progressive Web Apps with Microsoft Edge.
In 'Tileiconifier' I can find websites I've made as PWAs/Progressive Web Apps using Brave, but NOT the websites as PWAs/Progressive Web Apps made using Microsoft Edge.
Can anybody help me with getting  'Tileiconifier' to find the PWAs/Progressive Web Apps made via Microsoft Edge?
I can find the actual Microsoft Edge Web Browser itself with 'Tileiconifier' but NOT the websites installed as PWAs/Progressive Web Apps from Microsoft Edge.
